# Fixing the seed for torch random_split()

Tags: pytorch, torch

Is it possible to fix the seed for `torch.utils.data.random_split()` when splitting a dataset so that it is possible to reproduce the test results?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `torch.manual_seed` function to seed the script globally:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

See [reproducibility documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) for more information.

If you want to specifically seed `torch.utils.data.random_split` you could "reset" the seed to it's initial value afterwards. Simply use [`torch.initial_seed()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.initial_seed) like this:

```
torch.manual_seed(torch.initial_seed())
```

AFAIK `pytorch` **does not** provide arguments like `seed` or `random_state` (which could be seen in `sklearn` for example).

Answer (score 17):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) is possible to pass a generator to random_split

```
random_split(range(10), [3, 7], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
generator = torch.Generator()
generator.manual_seed(0)

train, val, test = random_split(dataset=dataset,
                                lengths=[train_size, val_size, test_size],
                                generator=generator)
```